# bash code for run a php script in local network

Tags: linux, bash

i need help in this code
this is a bash code for run a php script in local network

```
default_ip=$(hostname -I)
printf "Put your local IP (Default %s): " $default_ip
read ip
ip="${ip:-${default_ip}}"
sudo php -t "$server" -S "$ip:80" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

when i change `read ip` to `ip=$default_ip` it's dont work
i need to make this code auto run with out `read ip`
auto run like just run the code without write in the commands in the terminal

Comment: Why is the question tagged as `python`?

Comment: I tried your code.  I added `#!/bin/bash` in the first line, and commented out the last line, since I do not have your php setup.  If I remove `read ip` and put `ip=$default_ip` all is well.  I pring the value of $ip and it is ok with the read line or the ip=... line.

Comment: i used '''#!/bin/bash''' but it's don't work  this is the code : https://github.com/byRo0t96/open_server/blob/master/start.sh

Comment: "it's dont work" is not a problem description with which we can help you. You need to be more precise when describe the problem. See also [ask].